# Python Data-Scraping Differentiation - millions vs. ones

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm currently scraping some tables on the internet where numbers are posted in varying numerical formats:

```
Animal - Left in Wild
Tigers - 18
Deer - 18m
Pigs - 180000
```

I've managed to strip the m away from the number, but I am wondering if/how I could use a if statement to allow some manipulation to ensure I document the number accurately:

```
if animal.strip("m") == animal.strip("m"):
    left_in_wild = left_in_wild * 1000000
```

*Obviously that code does not work, but it is a rough thought* of how I'm thinking about getting around this. If anyone can has anything they think can be helpful let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple IF statement could help with what you're looking for:

```
animal = "18m"

if 'm' in animal:
    print animal.strip('m') + ",000,000"

if 'k' in animal:
    print animal.strip('k') + ",000"
```

returns:

```
18,000,000
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import re

def get_number(s):
    try: 
        i=int(re.match('(\d+)', s).group(1))
        if "m" in s:
            i*=1000000
        return i
    except:
        print "No Number"
```

`get_numbers("18m")` returns `18000000`

You could even expand it to have an `elif "k" in s` block if you had thousands or something.

Comment: If you are going to compile the expression on the spot, use `re.match('(\d+)', s).group(1)` instead. If you want to use the precompiled version, put it outside your function, or make it a default parameter.

Comment: Good call. Updated. Thanks!